# How to format SQL with multiple variables per line in SSMS or DataGrip

Tags: sql, format, ssms, datagrip

is there an sql formatting feature in SSMS or DataGrip that formats expressions with multiple variables per line? / multiple columns for sql insert and select statements?

like

```
insert into many_col_tbl
( col_1,       col_2,      col3,
  ...
  col_99,      col_100,    col101)
values
( @col_1,      @col_2,      @col3,
   ...
  @col_99,     @col_100,    @col101)
```

I am working in the T-SQL ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no native support for SQL formatting in SSMS, however this can ba achieved with external plugins, like f.eks [Apex SQL Refactor](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_refactor.aspx)